# Creating an Averaged dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, average

```
From country    Austria Belgium Denmark France  Germany Italy   Luxembourg  Switzerland The Netherlands United Kingdom
Austria 0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   6   1
Belgium 0   0   0   2   1   1   0   0   5   1
Denmark 0   2   0   2   0   1   0   2   3   0
France  0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   4   0
Germany 0   2   0   6   0   0   0   1   1   0
Italy   0   0   3   0   1   0   4   1   1   0
Luxembourg  0   0   0   4   0   1   0   1   3   1
Switzerland 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   2
The Netherlands 1   0   5   1   0   2   0   0   0   1
United Kingdom  2   0   2   2   0   2   1   0   1   0
```

Here I have a table where the values are points assigned from a country to a country on the columns. I have 60 tables total, I'm trying to create one final table that looks the same but the values are the average over all 60 tables. I haven't been able to find any function in pandas or elsewhere in stack exchange that averages each value like I'm trying to do, how can I approach this problem?

PS: In some tables there are more or less countries

Comment: All tables are in files?

Comment: Yeah, they're each in a xlsx file, which I'm using pd.read_excel() to load into a dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) with parameter `sheetname=None` for `dict` of `Dataframes` first. Then create big `df` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by second level of `index` and aggregate `mean`:

```
dict_dfs = pd.read_excel('multiple_sheets.xlsx', sheetname=None)
print (dict_dfs)
{'sheetname1':    a  b
0  1  4
1  2  8, 'sheetname2':    a  b
0  7  1
1  5  0, 'sheetname3':    a  b
0  4  5}

df = pd.concat(dict_dfs)
print (df)
              a  b
sheetname1 0  1  4
           1  2  8
sheetname2 0  7  1
           1  5  0
sheetname3 0  4  5

df = df.groupby(level=1).mean()
print (df)
     a         b
0  4.0  3.333333
1  3.5  4.000000
```

EDIT:

Sample with your data [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/multiple_sheets.xlsx):

```
dict_dfs = pd.read_excel('multiple_sheets.xlsx', sheetname=None, index_col=0)
df = pd.concat(dict_dfs)

df = df.groupby(level=1).mean()
print (df)
                 Austria  Belgium  Denmark  France  Germany  Italy  \
Fromcountry                                                          
Austria                4        0        0       0        0      0   
Belgium                0        0        0       2        1      1   
Denmark                0        2        0       2        0      1   
France                 0        0        0       0        6      0   
Germany                0        2        0       6        0      0   
Italy                  0        0        3       0        1      0   
Luxembourg             0        0        0       4        0      1   
Switzerland            0        1        0       0        0      0   
The Netherlands        1        0        5       1        0      2   
USA                    3        4        0       0        0      0   
United Kingdom         2        0        2       2        0      2   

                 Luxembourg  Switzerland  The Netherlands  USA  United Kingdom  
Fromcountry                                                                     
Austria                   3            0                6  4.0               1  
Belgium                   0            0                5  4.0               1  
Denmark                   0            2                3  5.0               0  
France                    0            0                4  0.0               0  
Germany                   0            1                1  0.0               0  
Italy                     4            1                1  0.0               0  
Luxembourg                0            1                3  0.0               1  
Switzerland               0            0                7  0.0               2  
The Netherlands           0            0                0  0.0               1  
USA                       0            0                0  0.0               0  
United Kingdom            1            0                1  0.0               0
```

If there is multiple coutries, last use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for filtering by reference `index` and `columns` names:

```
#reference sheetname - sheetname1
idx = dict_dfs['sheetname1'].index
cols = dict_dfs['sheetname1'].columns

df = df.reindex(index=idx, columns=cols)
print (df)
                 Austria  Belgium  Denmark  France  Germany  Italy  \
Fromcountry                                                          
Austria                4        0        0       0        0      0   
Belgium                0        0        0       2        1      1   
Denmark                0        2        0       2        0      1   
France                 0        0        0       0        6      0   
Germany                0        2        0       6        0      0   
Italy                  0        0        3       0        1      0   
Luxembourg             0        0        0       4        0      1   
Switzerland            0        1        0       0        0      0   
The Netherlands        1        0        5       1        0      2   
United Kingdom         2        0        2       2        0      2   

                 Luxembourg  Switzerland  The Netherlands  United Kingdom  
Fromcountry                                                                
Austria                   3            0                6               1  
Belgium                   0            0                5               1  
Denmark                   0            2                3               0  
France                    0            0                4               0  
Germany                   0            1                1               0  
Italy                     4            1                1               0  
Luxembourg                0            1                3               1  
Switzerland               0            0                7               2  
The Netherlands           0            0                0               1  
United Kingdom            1            0                1               0
```

Comment: What is the keys arguement exactly? The documentation doesn't really clear things up for me "keys : sequence, default None
        If multiple levels passed, should contain tuples. Construct
        hierarchical index using the passed keys as the outermost level"
and on the same note, what does the names list supposed to represent?

Comment: This is very cool, I have to look more into the groupby method. But is there a way to preserve the index of the table, ie: the from countries?

Comment: I am not sure if understand - coutry  index is not in excel file?

Comment: It is, but what I output to a new excel from df = df.groupby(level=1).mean() the index is lost and just replaced by numbers not the countries name

Comment: And after `df = pd.concat(dict_dfs)
print (df)` index has coutry names? `Groupby` remove it?

Comment: Correct, it's fine before I use groupby

Comment: What is `df.index` after `concat` ?

Comment: Lot of effort and good information.  Definitely more that useful.  Downright great answer as usual.

Comment: @GrahamChapman even if this post wasn't your chosen answer, it is very useful and provides a lot of content from which to learn.  It would be appropriate to upvote this answer as well.

Comment: @piRSquared - Hmmm, if 2 good answers, OP has to decide which can be accepted.

Comment: @jezrael OP has already decided.  I just want to see an up vote where it's deserved.

Comment: @piRSquared - yes, exactly. Thank you.

Comment: I've spent the last few days trying to work through this a little more. I'm not an expert on pandas and I don't find the documentation very helpful in terms of what everything does so it takes me a little longer to understand what things are doing. I've found that I do have more control over the data I'm working with in your solution which is why I have marked it as the solution to my answer. However, I have one problem, when I use groupby() I lose only 1 country in the columns? Can you explain this perhaps and how to fix it?

Comment: Thank you. I think problem is your column is not numeric, so if aggregate `mean` column is removed - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns).

Comment: It can be checked by `print (df.dtypes)`.

Comment: I checked the dtype, after concat the country becomes an object instead of a float. I checked my script that creates the multisheet.xlsx and everything is an int64 when it gets put into the multisheet. So it must be happening when it gets loaded into the dict_dfs or somehow during the concat?

Comment: It seems weird, are your data confidental?

Comment: Thank for all your help! I found the problem was a non scaler value in the data. Fixed that and everything else works!

Comment: Glad can help you!

Answer (score 2):

Assume we have a list of dataframes `tables`

```
tables = [df.set_index('From country').copy() for _ in range(10)]
```

Where we set the index to `'From country'` just incase it wasn't already the index.  Skip that part if it already is.

Then we convert the list of dataframes to a `pd.Panel` and take the mean over the zero axis

```
pd.Panel(dict(enumerate(tables))).mean(0)
```

if `tables` is already a dictionary, then we just need to pass that directly to `pd.Panel`

```
pd.Panel(tables).mean(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Btw, I think reindex is necessary too, because if in some tables is more data, in some less, is necessary filter out unnecessary data.